# Python: Munging data with '.join' (TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found)

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have data in following format:

```
[('A', 'B', 'C'),
 ('B', 'C', 'A'),
 ('C', 'B', 'B')]
```

I'm looking to get this:

```
ABC
BCA
CBB
```

I'm able to convert one tuple at the time:

```
>> "".join(data[0])
.. 'ABC'
```

However when I'm trying to conver the whole list Python gives me an error:

```
>> "".join(data[:])
.. TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found
```

Any advice how I'll be able to convert the whole list?

Thank you!

Comment: btw, `data[:]` and `data` has same effect

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`.join` expects a sequence of strings, but you're giving it a sequence of tuples.

To get the result you posted, you'll need to join each element in each tuple, and then join each tuple together:

```
print('\n'.join(''.join(elems) for elems in data))
```

This works because `.join` will accept a generator expression, allowing you to iterate over `data` (your list of tuples).

We therefore have two joins going on: the inner join builds a string of the three letters (eg, `'ABC'`), and the outer join places newline characters (`'\n'`) between them.

Comment: One other way you can mistakenly pass `.join` a sequence of tuples is by accidentally writing `''.join(elems) for elem in elems`, elems being the iterable with the split strings. That will produce this error message.

Answer (score 3):

```
lst=[('A', 'B', 'C'),
 ('B', 'C', 'A'),
 ('C', 'B', 'B')]

for x in lst:
    print ("".join(x))
```

Output is;

```
>>> 
ABC
BCA
CBB
>>>
```

One-liner;

```
print ("\n".join(["".join(x) for x in lst]))
```

You have to reach each element in the list first.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [('A', 'B', 'C'),  ('B', 'C', 'A'),  ('C', 'B', 'B')]
print ["".join(line) for line in a]
```